# extract data based on datetime

Tags: r, datetime, merge, lapply

I have two dataframes:

- dat is a 9752x8 dataframe that contains some POSIXlt dates
- trips.df  is a 35772x28 dataframe that contains hourly temperature
  data

I would like to save the corresponding temperature for each dates in dat.

I have tried:

```
trips.df$temperature<-lapply(trips.df$fin, function(x){
   dat_meteo[dat_meteo$Date.Heure==round(x,"hours"),7]})
```

But I got this error, which makes me think that x is not passed as a datetime variable

```
 Error in round(x, "hours") : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I have also tried this:

```
merge(trips.df,dat_meteo[,c(1,7)])
```

But I also got an error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 653.8 Mb
```

Any advice on how to retrieve data on dat_meteo by dates?

I am using R version 3.4.0  with RStudio Version 1.0.143  on Windows 10
And here are an exercpt of my data:

```
> head(trips.df$fin)
[1] "2013-06-25 16:34:16 EDT" "2013-06-25 16:34:16 EDT" "2013-06-26 13:00:05 EDT"
[4] "2013-06-29 12:52:21 EDT" "2013-06-29 15:34:13 EDT" "2013-06-29 17:39:29 EDT"
> dat_meteo[1870:1875,c(1,7)]
              Date.Heure Temp...C.
1870 2013-03-19 18:00:00      -1,2
1871 2013-03-19 19:00:00      -1,7
1872 2013-03-19 20:00:00      -2,1
1873 2013-03-19 21:00:00      -2,8
1874 2013-03-19 22:00:00      -3,0
1875 2013-03-19 23:00:00      -3,7
```

Comment: Make sure that both your time columns are in the same format, for example `POSIXct`. `round()` actually seems to convert `POSIXct` to `POSIXlt`, so you could do `as.POSIXct(round(trips.df$fin,"hours"))`. Then you can use `match()` to get the corresponding indexes or `merge`, and it should work.

Comment: @Lamia,  thanks for your input. How would the code look like? I have tried this with no luck: `merge(trips.df,dat_meteo[1,7],by.x=as.POSIXct(round(trips.df$fin,"hours")),by.y = dat_meteo$Date.Heure)`

Comment: `by.x` and `by.y` need column names not the column themselves. Add another column to trips.df: `trips.df$finhours=as.POSIXct(round(trips.df‌​$fin,"hours"))`, then perform `merge(trips.df,dat_meteo[,c(1,7)],by.x="finhours",by.y ="Date.Heure")`.

Comment: Still not working. I have tried `dat_meteo[dat_meteo$Date.Heure==trips.df$fin_r[1],]` and it returns the correct values in `dat_meteo`. That tells me that `fin_r`  (or finhours) and `Date.Heure` are the same. But `merge` does not return anything and `trips.df$fin_r%in% dat_meteo$Date.Heure` is false everywhere...

Comment: Are you sure that `dat_meteo$Date.Heure` is not a `POSIXlt`? `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` are two completely different formats. You should include a str() of your 2 dataframes in your question.

Comment: You were right! `dat_meteo$Date.Heure` was not a `POSIXct`. If you post your first comment, I'll accept i as an answer.

Comment: This question was difficult to answer because it was lacking a [mcve]. Next time, please, use `dput(x)` to supply _working_ data. With `dput()` it would have been instantly obvious what data types you were using (better than `str()`. The excerpts of your data printed in your question neither show the data type nor do they fit together to make up a working example (time/date ranges don't overlap). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the two time columns you want to match have the same format (`POSIXct`). It is more straightforward to use the `POSIXct` format within a dataframe, as the `POSIXlt` format actually corresponds to a list of named elements whereas `POSIXct` is in vector form.

```
dat_meteo$Date.Heure=as.POSIXct(dat_meteo$Date.Heure,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Create a column in trips.df of times rounded to the closest hours, converting it to `POSIXct` too, as round converts `POSIXct` to `POSIXlt`:

```
trips.df$fin_r=as.POSIXct(round(trips.df‌​$fin,"hours"))
```

Then use `merge`:

```
res=merge(trips.df,dat_meteo[,c(1,7)],by.x="fin_r",by.y ="Date.Heure")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a slightly different approach and use `data.table`.

```
trips.dt <- data.table(trips.df)
dat      <- data.table(dat)
trips.dt <- trips.dt[ , dates.a := strptime(as.POSIXct(fin,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),format='%m/%d/%Y')][,dates.b := dates.a]
dat      <- dat[dates.dat.a := strptime(as.POSIXct(Date.Heure, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),format='%m/%d/%Y')][, dates.dat.b := dates.dat.a]
setkey(trips.dt, id, dates.a, dates.b)
setkey(dat , id, dates.dat.a, dates.dat.b)
combo    <- foverlaps(trips.df, dat, type = "within")
```

This creates date ranges for both `trip.df` and `dat` after converting it to a `data.table`, then merges `trips.df` to `dat` and stores the result as `combo`

Comment: Thx! I was not familiar with data.table. One question though, what does `dates.a` and `dates.dat.a` stand for?

Comment: Nothing. I more or less just didn't want to overwrite the original variable.